# What Jensen inequality implies in it holds with equality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, jensen-inequality

For any measurable function $f$, Jensen inequality states that $\int \phi (f) d\mu \geq \phi ( \int f d\mu)$ for convex $\phi$.

Is there a proof that if the inequality holds with equality, that is 
$$\int \phi (f) d\mu = \phi ( \int f d\mu)$$
for every measurable $f$, then $\phi$ must be affine?

I was trying to assume, by contradiction, that (assuming differentiability and strict convexity of $\phi$ and strict convexity)
$$\phi(f)>\phi(c)+\phi’(c)(f-c)$$
With $c= \int f d\mu$, and then I would integrate on both sides and reach a contradiction. However, the strict inequality above is not true in general, as it may exists an $x \in X$ such that the rhs is equal to the lhs, so my ‘proof’ would be invalid. 
Do you know if what I am trying to show is true? And what’s the proof?

Answer (score 2):

The question implicitly used $\mu(X)=1$.

If $\phi$ is not affine, then there are numbers $a,b$  and $\lambda\in(0,1)$ such that
$$
\phi(\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b)< \lambda \phi(a) + (1-\lambda)\phi(b).
$$
Now let $A$ be a measurable set with measure equal to $\lambda$, then its complement $A^c$ has measure and $(1-\lambda)$. Define
$$
f:=\chi_A \cdot a + \chi_{A^c}\cdot b,
$$
which implies
$$
\phi(\int f)  = \phi(\lambda a + (1-\lambda)b) 
< \lambda \phi(a) + (1-\lambda)\phi(b) = \int \phi(f).
$$
Thus, $f$ is the desired function, that yields strict inequality in Jensen.